# Using parallel programing to evaluate the result of the first executed method

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Given the following array `Func<int>[] funcs` and using TPL (Task Parallel Library .NET) how can I evaluate the first result returned by the invocation of any of the functions in `funcs`.

The main constraint here is to run all of the methods in parallel and stop when the first is returned.

The method definition is something like this:

```
public static int EvalFirstResult(Func<int>[] funcs);
```

Comment: Did you want to ran them parallel, wait for first task completed, and run away or cancelling of other tasks is important?

Comment: After the first one is completed i don't want to wait for the result of the others. I just need the result of the first function completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first we need to turn each function into a `Task`.  That's done with `Select` and `Task.Run`.  Then, once we have that, we can just use `Task.WaitAny` to get the result of the first task to finish.

```
var tasks = funcs.Select(function => Task.Run(function)).ToArray();
int result = Task.WaitAny(tasks);
```

Note that the remaining tasks will still finish; we're not *stopping* them, we're just ignoring their results.

Comment: I need to return after one of the functions is completed. I don't want to wait for every function to complete. By the way, i can't use Task.Run in .NET 4.5 (method doesn't exists).

Comment: Based on your answer I managed to get it.

var tasks = funcs.Select(f => Task.Factory.StartNew(f)).ToArray();
return Task.WaitAny(tasks);

Thanks!

Comment: @illusionpt `Task.Run` was added in 4.5.  If you don't have it then you must be on 4.0.